# Loop back to for iteration

Tags: jquery

I am trying to compare two values. if the value equals then the loop must break and goto next for iteration.This is code I am using.

```
forLoop:
for (var i = 1, len = values.length; i < len; i++) {
    $('.charStyleAddedToDoc .char-style-added h4')
        .each(function(index, element) {
            //check if value matches
            if ($(element)
                .text() == values[i]) {
                // shoud go next for iteration in for loop
                break forLoop;
            }
        });
    html += '<div class="prog-row side-mini-stat clearfix"><div class="char-style-available"><h4>' + values[i] + '</h4></div></div>';
}
```

I am getting as label is not defined in (break forLoop;) line.

Comment: You can only use `break` and `continue` in the immediate body of a loop (or switch or label statement). It doesn't work across function boundaries. The only way to "break" from an `.each` "loop" is to use `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
var flag;
for (var i = 1, len = values.length; i < len; i++) {
    //a flag variable to store the state from the each loop
    flag = false;
    $('.charStyleAddedToDoc .char-style-added h4')
        .each(function (index, element) {
        //check if value matches
        if ($(element)
            .text() == values[i]) {
            // shoud go next for iteration in for loop
            //set the flag to true so that we can skip remainder of the for loop
            flag = true;
            //return false to skip further execution of the each loop
            return false;
        }
    });
    //if the flag is set then we can skip the remainder of the loop
    if (flag) {
        continue;
    }
    html += '<div class="prog-row side-mini-stat clearfix"><div class="char-style-available"><h4>' + values[i] + '</h4></div></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) instead of `break`:

```
                        for(var i=1, len = values.length; i<len; i++){
                            $('.charStyleAddedToDoc .char-style-added h4').each(function(index,element){
                                //check if value matches
                                if($(element).text() == values[i]){
                                    // shoud go next for iteration in for loop
                                    continue;
                                }

                            });
                            html+='<div class="prog-row side-mini-stat clearfix"><div class="char-style-available"><h4>'+values[i]+'</h4></div></div>';
                        }
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement`

Comment: @FelixKling Hmm. According to the MDN you can but a `continue` statement inside a conditional statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue

Comment: @Nathan: yes, but that `if` statement has to be inside a loop. Yours isn't, the function creates a new lexical environment.

Comment: @Nathan - you're putting the `continue` statment inside the `.each()` callback which means the `continue` is just in a function and not in a loop.  If the OP wants better loop control, they have to stop using `.each()` and use a `while` or `for` loop.  This is a classic drawback of `.each()` callbacks.

Comment: @FelixKling Ah I see, well this isn't my code, I just changed `break` to `continue`. I wonder how this can be accomplished when one needs to check multiple elements like the OP is doing in the for loop.

Comment: It's still your solution ;) As jfriend00 said, you wouldn't use `.each(...)` in that case.

Comment: getting as label not found

Comment: @FelixKling Fair enough :P I guess `.each(...)` can still be used, check out Arun's answer.

Answer (score 0):

syntax of label and goto in javascript is:

```
[lbl] <label-name>
goto <label-name>
```

Try this using label and goto statements.

```
[lbl] forLoop:
    for (var i = 1, len = values.length; i < len; i++) {
        $('.charStyleAddedToDoc .char-style-added h4')
            .each(function(index, element) {
                //check if value matches
                if ($(element)
                    .text() == values[i]) {
                    // shoud go next for iteration in for loop
                    goto forLoop;
                }
            });
        html += '<div class="prog-row side-mini-stat clearfix"><div class="char-style-available"><h4>' + values[i] + '</h4></div></div>';
    }
```